SQL Server Geometry Lat/Long
I'm trying to get lat/longs from a SQL Server Geometry table. The projection is Lambert Conformal Conic, coordinate system is EPSG:4269, so some kind of projection is needed.
I know this can only be done with 3rd party tools and so I downloaded SQL Server Spatial Tools. Based on the Tool's documentation something like this should work, but the kind of coordinates I got are nonsensical.
select @LambertConformalConic.UnprojectWithSRID('POINT (-305577.363799997 94517.064100001)',4269).ToString()

Does anyone know of a better way or tool to do what I want? This needs to be done with T-SQL so I can't use Pro or other ArcGIS products.

Maybe this will help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368970/how-to-transform-the-lambert-conformal-conic-projection-to-latitude-longitude-co

Can you post whole code? from which srid and to which srid do you want to project your coordinates to?

The table's coordinate system is 4269 and I'm trying to get lat/longs from xy. The code I posted uses values from a record from the table which is in 4269. The resulting xy should be in lat/long but the values are invalid.

QGIS and ESRI products are options. This has to be done in SQL.

I don't quite get your code.
UnprojectWithSRID accepts a geometry and converts it to the second parameter SRID, see https://github.com/microsoft/SQLServerSpatialTools/blob/master/src/Types/SQL/SqlProjection.cs#L205
So, it should probably be: 4326 in second parameter, if you want to convert to regular mercator. And first parameter should have 4269 SRID. But you're passing string, which is converted to a geometry with 0 SRID, see:
select cast('POINT (-305577.363799997 94517.064100001)' as geometry).STSrid -- Returns 0

What you want is probably explicitely set SRID when creating your geometry:
select GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (-305577.363799997 94517.064100001)', 4269) -- Returns 4269

Final code:
select @LambertConformalConic.UnprojectWithSRID(
  GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (-305577.363799997 94517.064100001)', 4269),4326
 ).ToString()

Edit: although, maybe you don't need to set input geometry SRID, but it's hard to know if UnprojectWithSRID uses it so i'd probably set it anyway.
